# Purpose of the capacitor which is placed in parallel to collector and emitter of the transistor?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, output, buzzer

Can someone explain the purpose of the **C469** capacitor, which placed in parallel to collector and emitter of the transistor?

[image: Gigabyte G31 Speaker Connector]

Edit: Sorry for the mistake, C469 is parallel to CE

Comment: C469 is in **parallel** with the collector and emitter.

Comment: It's not in series. It's in parallel to the transistor.

Comment: sorry for the mistake, now I modify the post.

Comment: What kind of buzzer, piezo or electromagnetic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it is for damping the inductive kickback from the external speaker. There is no other mechanism for handling it, such as diode between speaker pins.

Comment: Can you name 1 reason why this method was used instead of a reliable diode method?

Comment: Sure. For the same reason diodes are not used with relay coils either. It quenches the energy stored in the speaker coil faster. It acts as a low pass filter for higher frequencies too. It does cause current surges when the transistor turns on. PC motherboards are extremely cheaply designed. The first IBM PC, the model 5150, also had a capacitor directly on the open-drain output driver, it just was a 10nF instead of 100nF.

Comment: I agree diodes can slow the release arc time yet diodes are used more often and hundreds of others have suggested that in this forum.  So wouldn't a capacitor also slow down magnetic switch arc time in a buzzer? and lower resonant frequency yet reduce current in addition to lower EMI?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the buzzer is electrically noisy and they wanted to suppress some of the higher frequency spikes that are coming from it.